# jquery how to properly increment a value

Tags: jquery

I have a button which has a value each time a user clicks that button the value suppose to go up by 1. This works but not how I would like for instance for there are no clicks then the buttons value is **0** if a user clicks then the value goes to **01** instead of **1**. How can I go about resolving this? I been stuck admittingly I am new to Jquery.

```
                var cfollowers = $('#cfollowers').val()+1;
                $('#cfollowers').val(cfollowers);


                   <input type="button" id="cfollowers"  value="0" />
```

Comment: Why do you want `01`?

Comment: Rather than relying solely on the DOM and the jquery objects to contain the value, it might be better to store the value somewhere else, and simply have jquery update it.

Comment: You make a good point I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the value of an input element is reprented as a string, so you are concatenating strings rather than adding integers.  Just add a parseInt call to your code to fix the issue:

```
<input type="button" id="cfollowers"  value="0" />
<script>
    $('#cfollowers').click( function() {
        var cfollowers = parseInt($('#cfollowers').val())+1;
        $('#cfollowers').val(cfollowers);
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:** *docodemore* makes a good point!  A better way to approach this would be to store the value of the button as a separate variable.

```
<input type="button" id="cfollowers"  value="0" />
<script>
    var cfollowers = 0;
    $('#cfollowers').click( function() {
        cfollowers++;
        $('#cfollowers').val(cfollowers);
    });
</script>
```